# jQuery UI Slider and Checkbox to filter set of divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jquery here.

I am running a ajax call to return an SQL query. It basically displays a list of properties, each property has a class name consisting of the development name, the number of bedrooms and whether or not it is a match or nomatch depending on wether or not is matches the checkbox value.

Upon each checkbox click the divs are hidden if they do not match the required parameter.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cactuscreative/2PM8H/4/

jQuery

```
                $(function() {
                    $('#slider-range').slider({
                        range: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 700000,
                        step: 5000,
                        values: [ 25000, 550000 ],
                        slide: function(event, ui) {
                            $( "#price_range" ).val( "£" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - £" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                        }, 
                        stop: function(event, ui) {
                            mi = ui.values[ 0 ];
                            mx = ui.values[ 1 ];
                            filterSystem(mi, mx);
                        }
                    });
                    $( "#price_range" ).val( "£" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - £" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
                });

                function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
                    $("div.plotresult").filter(function() {
                        var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"));
                        if (isNaN(price)) { price = '0'; }
                        console.log(price);
                        $("div.plotresult").hide();
                        $("div.plotresult").removeClass('match').addClass('nomatch');
                        return price > minPrice && price < maxPrice;
                    }).show();
                }

                $(".filter:checkbox").bind('change',function () {
                    $("div.plotresult").hide();
                    $("div.plotresult").removeClass('match').addClass('nomatch');
                    $("div#overlay").show();

                    var locationArray = [];
                    var bedroomArray = [];

                    var location_Count = 0, bedroom_Count = 0;

                    $("#location :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                        locationArray[location_Count] = $(this).val();
                        location_Count++
                    });

                    $("#bedroom :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                        bedroomArray[bedroom_Count] = $(this).val();
                        bedroom_Count++
                    });

                    var locationstring
                    var bedroonstring

                    var locationchecked = false
                    var bedroomchecked = false

                    if (bedroom_Count == 0) { bedroom_Count = 1; } else { bedroomchecked = true; }
                    if (location_Count == 0) { location_Count = 1; } else { locationchecked = true; }

                    for (f2 = 0; f2 < location_Count; f2++) {
                        if (locationArray[f2] != null) { locationstring = '.' + locationArray[f2] } else { locationstring = '' }
                    }

                    for (f3 = 0; f3 < bedroom_Count; f3++) {
                        if (bedroomArray[f3] != null) { bedroomstring = '.' + bedroomArray[f3] } else { bedroomstring = '' }
                    }

                    var QueryString = locationstring + bedroomstring

                    $(QueryString).removeClass('nomatch').addClass('match').fadeIn('slow');

                    if (!locationchecked && !bedroomchecked) {
                        $("div.plotresult").removeClass('nomatch').addClass('match').fadeIn('slow');
                    };

                    var mycount = $('.match').length;
                    $(".totalRes").text(mycount);
                });                     

                $('a.showall').click(function () {
                    $("div.plotresult").removeClass('nomatch').addClass('match').fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#price :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
                    $("#location :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
                    $("#price :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
                    var mycount = $('.match').length;
                    $(".totalRes").text(mycount);
                    return false;
                });
```

Filters

```
                <div class="searchfields">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div id="filters">
                            <div class="locations" id="location">
                                <h3>Location</h3>
                                <div class="cumboptions checks">
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" id="cumbria" /> <label><strong>Cumbria</strong></label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="location" id="CumbridgeDrive" value="cambridgedrive" /> <label>Cambridge Drive, Penrith</label></p>  
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="location" id="HawksdalePastures" value="hawksdalepastures" /> <label>Hawksdale Pastures, Dalston</label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="location" id="CraggClose" value="craggclose" /> <label>Cragg Close, Kendal</label></p>   
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="location" id="MastersGrange" value="mastersgrange" /> <label>Masters’ Grange, Kirkby Lonsdale</label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="location" id="Pengarth" value="pengarth" /> <label>Pengarth, Grange-over-Sands</label></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="yorkoptions checks">
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" id="yorkshire" /> <label><strong>North Yorkshire</strong></label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="location" id="ImperialCourt" value="imperialcourt" /> <label>Imperial Court, Ingleton</label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="location" id="OldLaundryMews" value="oldlaundrymews" /> <label>Old Laundry Mews, Ingleton</label></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="rooms" id="bedroom">
                                <h3>Number of Bedrooms</h3>
                                <div class="options bedrooms">
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="bedroom" id="one" value="one" /> <label>1</label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="bedroom" id="two" value="two" /> <label>2</label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="bedroom" id="three" value="three" /> <label>3</label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="bedroom" id="four" value="four" /> <label>4</label></p>
                                    <p><input type="checkbox" class="filter" name="bedroom" id="four" value="five" /> <label>5</label></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="prices" id="price">
                                <h3>Price (£)</h3>
                                <div class="options">
                                    <input type="text" id="price_range" class="price_range" value="" />
                                    <div id="slider-range"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p><a class="showall" href="#">Clear Filters</a></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Results:

```
<div id="result">
    <h4 class="countresults"><span class="totalRes">6</span> properties match your result</h4>

<div class="plot plotresult mastersgrange three" data-price="0">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x620" width="100%" />
    <p class="meta">Masters Grange Plot 26</p>
     <h3>3 Bedroom Detached House</h3>

    <p class="info"></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="price">£TBC</li>
        <li class="rooms">3 Bedrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="plot plotresult cambridgedrive four" data-price="395000">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x620" width="100%" />
    <p class="meta">Cambridge Drive Plot 34</p>
     <h3>4 Bedroom Detached House</h3>

    <p class="info"></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="price">£395000</li>
        <li class="rooms">4 Bedrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="plot plotresult craggclose two" data-price="250000">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x620" width="100%" />
    <p class="meta">Cragg Close Plot 18</p>
     <h3>2 Bedroom Detached House</h3>

    <p class="info"></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="price">£250000</li>
        <li class="rooms">2 Bedrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="plot plotresult pengarth three" data-price="0">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x620" width="100%" />
    <p class="meta">Pengarth Plot 8</p>
     <h3>2 Bedroom Detached House</h3>

    <p class="info"></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="price">£TBC</li>
        <li class="rooms">3 Bedrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="plot plotresult pengarth three" data-price="250000">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x620" width="100%" />
    <p class="meta">Pengarth Plot 10</p>
     <h3>3 Bedroom Detached House</h3>

    <p class="info"></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="price">£250000</li>
        <li class="rooms">3 Bedrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="plot plotresult hawksdalepastures four" data-price="550000">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x620" width="100%" />
    <p class="meta">hawksdalepastures Plot 65</p>
     <h3>4 Bedroom Detached House</h3>

    <p class="info"></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="price">£550000</li>
        <li class="rooms">4 Bedrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My issue is that they don't play together.

They work as individual filters but if I want to check a development and bedrooms and then between a price bracket then it ignores the checkbox.

Visa versa - i set a price bracket and its ok, then i check a development and bedrooms and it ignores the price bracket.

Any Help would be amazing...

Comment: Nice question, `name="bedroom" id="four" value="five"` you have two "four" id's in there, could be a problem.. Trying to break your fiddle after fixing that and having difficulty.. seems to work fine for me..

Comment: you sure? i know they work independently but i want them to work together. select a development then a price. I also notice the slider doesn't update the number of properties found to which would help better demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cactuscreative/2PM8H/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone for a slightly different approach to how your example worked which simplifies the code a lot.

If you have an object to store the search state then you can just then run a search function every time a checkbox is ticked/unticked and the slider updates. Adding data-location and data-bedrooms attributes to each plot also makes things easier for filtering rather than relying on the class names.

See full working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/77ZLC/

The general gist of it works like so:

```
// store search state
var search = {
    minPrice: 25000, 
    maxPrice: 550000,
    locations: [],
    bedrooms: []
};

/**
 * Do a search and update results
 */
function doSearch() {

    var numResults = 0;

    $('.plotresult').each(function(el) {

        $el = $(this);

        var location = $el.data('location');
        var bedrooms = $el.data('bedrooms');
        var price = $el.data('price');

        var show = true;

        // check locations
        if (search.locations.length > 0 && $.inArray(location, search.locations) === -1) {
            show = false;
        }

        // check bedrooms
        if (search.bedrooms.length > 0 && $.inArray(bedrooms, search.bedrooms) === -1) {
            show = false;
        }

        // check price
        var price = parseInt(price, 10) || 0;
        if (price < search.minPrice || price > search.maxPrice) {
            show = false;
        }

        if (show) {
            numResults++;
            $el.removeClass('nomatch').addClass('match');
        }
        else {
            $el.removeClass('match').addClass('nomatch');
        }

    });

    // show/hide results
    $('.match').fadeIn();
    $('.nomatch').fadeOut();

    // update total
    $('.totalRes').text(numResults);

};
```

Comment: Awesome - this is so close too. Doesn't seem to work on my site though which I driving me mental. clear filters works fine but not the checking of the boxes? why would it work on the fiddle and not on my site.I have check and there doesn't seem to be any conflicts and no errors on console.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it. You need to add all of your filters to run in one place so you can pass extra params to an event when you trigger it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/2PM8H/8/

In this example I've change your filter function to trigger the change event of a checkbox and therefore run through the currently selected filters adding my own at the end:

```
function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
    $(".filter:checkbox").trigger("change", [minPrice,maxPrice]);
}
```

There's a bit of a bug with the fading in then out again, but I'll let you handle that one ;-)